# Auto Layout Top is not working well with 10px space at top

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios8, autolayout

I'm building iphone app. I use auto-layout.
Please check following images.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the top space is set as 0px. but in running, the top space is 10px.

I want to fix this issue asap. P.S. it is same on iOS7 & iOS8.
Thanks,

Comment: Go to `constraint->edit`. Set both *First Item* and *Second item* to *<view>.top*.
And make sure it's not **Relative to margin**.

Comment: Thanks okenstein, You are right. This issue is related with Relative to margin. This issue is fixed. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll post the answer, pls check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `constraint->edit`. Set both *First Item* and *Second item* to *.top*. And make sure it's not **Relative to margin**.